# Tesseract not detecting white characters

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision, python-tesseract

Ive been trying to detect the white letters on a light blue background and it seems to work for same background but with slightly cleaner letters.

Here is the image - it returns no text from the OCR activity.
If I make background darker blue, its OK.
The text seems clear enough, maybe its some odd tesseract thing?

Thanks.

.[image]

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

image = cv2.imread('c3.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow('gray', gray)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,175 ,255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
thresh = 255 - thresh

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
result = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=1)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.imwrite('result.jpg', result)
invert = cv2.bitwise_not(result)

config = ''
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(invert, config=config)
cv2.imshow('result', invert)

print("Result: " + text)

cv2.waitKey()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things which are needed to be known in your case.

1. First of all, you need to get a clear image for input. Here is a beautiful [documentation](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html) you can find for that. I see you did some pre-processing steps like threshold, but at the end you are giving to the **tesseract** engine the first input. Then why did you do those steps ?
2. Second one and the most important one is that you need to know well about the **tesseract** configuration parameters. I see you are giving an empty config so the default one. I suggest you to use the config like below:

> config = r'--oem 1 --psm 6'
>
> - –psm 6 - Assume a single uniform block of text.
> - --oem 1 for LSTM/neural network

If you change the config accordingly, I got the output:

```
Result: MeN aRS Se
GESU 132857 (4)
aes NEE” «Sa ee
```

At least you are getting some good results. You can improve it by improving the input image quality by the help of pre-processing steps.

Comment: HI Yunus , I ran the input image through kernel_sharpen_1 = np.array([[-1,-1,-1], [-1,9,-1], [-1,-1,-1]]) and change thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,175 ,255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1], and now get the following output :   Result: GESU 432857 [4]    LEG!     ♀    , which is pretty close. Thanks!

Comment: Corrected code and threshold value